# How to do app-wide / faster updates by UI element type, in Swift using Xcode ...?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

Just curious - doing some maintenance on a swift app, bit time consuming, would love to know if there is a better recommended way, or faster way (?), to do mass updates for a UI element type, e.g. update all buttons, to have a certain property, e.g. say a color or width constraint...?

Comment: You can select multiple elements using Command+click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color, yes, by using the button's appearance proxy, like

```
UIButton.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.whateverColor()
```

Width constraint, no. There are a couple other ways to do it, though.

- If your regex skills are sharp, you can do a search & replace in all of the storyboards' and xibs' XML code to add a width constraint to each, but that'd be error-prone because some of them may already have width constraints.
- You can subclass `UIButton` and give it a width constraint and set any other properties you wish, but you'd still have to search-and-replace all `UIButton`s in the appearance files with your custom class type.

Answer (score 0):

For some mass updates, like changing fonts or colours of a control, you could use the UIAppearance proxy. You can also extend classes to add more options for controlling the design of views and controls. Just add methods marked with UI_APPEARANCE and implement as needed.